# Exported DAE file can only be opened by Mathematica, not preview nor xcode on mac

Tags: graphics3d, export

I built a simple model with 3D graphics and exported it to a DAE file, The 3D graphics looked good before export, but different and wrong after reimporting them from the DAE file.

Here is some sample code:

```
northEle = {Blue, Opacity[1], Cuboid[{-2, 2, 0}, {2, 2.1, 2}]};
southEle = {Blue, Opacity[1], Cuboid[{-2, -2, 0}, {2, -2.1, 2}]};
eastEle = {Blue, Opacity[1], Cuboid[{2, -2, 0}, {2.1, 2, 2}]};
westEle = {Blue, Opacity[1],  Cuboid[{-2, -2, 0}, {-2.1, 2, 2}]};
floorEle = {Brown, Opacity[1],  Cuboid[{-2, -2, 0}, {2, 2, 0.1}]};
test = Graphics3D[{northEle, southEle, eastEle, westEle, floorEle}]
```

[image: This is the image before export]

```
Export[
  "testRoom.dae", 
  Graphics3D[northWallEle, eastWallEle, westWallEle, southWallEle, floorEle]];

Import["testRoom.dae"]
```

[image: This is the image after Import from exported dae file]

Comment: Your variables have been renamed. Eg: `northEle` becomes `northWallEle` in your `Export`. Presumably you're exporting old data.

Comment: Also, I think `.dae` is for `MeshRegion`s, not `Graphics3D`.

Comment: @aardvark2012,  Yes, When I used MeshRegion, it works.  Thanks!